# Should i dockerize django app as non-root?

Tags: node.js, django, docker

Should i dockerize Django app as a root user? If yes how can i set up non-root user for Django? Because in node.js app should have USER:node which is a better practice.

Code example from official docker page which does not include non-root:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generically a good practice.

At the start of your Dockerfile, before you `COPY` anything in, create the user.  It doesn't need to have any specific properties and it doesn't need to match any specific host user ID.  The only particular reason to do this early is to avoid repeating it on rebuilds.

At the end of your Dockerfile, after you run all of the build steps, only then switch `USER` to the new user.  The code and any installed libraries will be owned by the root user; and that's good, because it means the application can't accidentally overwrite the application code.

```sh
FROM python:3

# Create the non-root user.  Doing this before any COPY means it won't
# be repeated on rebuild, for marginal savings in space and rebuild time.
# The user can have any name and any uid; it does not need to match any
# particular host system where the image might run.
RUN adduser --system --no-create-home someuser

# Install the application as in the question (still as root).
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

# Explain how to run the container.  Only switch to the non-root user now.
EXPOSE 8000
USER someuser
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

Do not try to write files inside the container; instead, use a separate database container for persistence.  Do not pass a host user ID as a build argument.  Do not configure a password for the user or otherwise attempt to set up interactive logins.  Do not create a home directory; it won't be used.

Comment: Can you clarify, what do you mean with "do not write files inside the container". What about logs, what about files that are potentially uploaded in this app? This is nothing a db (like SQL) should handle?

Comment: Logs should go to stdout.  If you can arrange for a separate service to store uploaded files that's also better; the ideal case is where you can run any number of copies of your application without mounting anything.